# Trouble displaying "@2x.png" images in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

My iphone app has two images: "cat.png" and "cat@2x.png"

I heard that if we want to display bigger image (for iPad version), then you give name as "@2x.png" & it automatically detects device & display bigger image in iPad.

Is that true? 
If yes, I have done the same thing, but it does not display "cat@2x.png" when I check in iPad.

What could be wrong?

NOTE: I know there are post discussing this thing for icon.png BUT in my case I am refering to all images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@2x is the extension for the iPhone 4 retina display. You want to store two versions of the image if you are releasing your app for the iPhone. e.g. myimage@2x.png and myimage.png.

Read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW8

Excerpt:

```
Standard: <ImageName><device_modifier>.<filename_extension> 
High resolution: <ImageName>@2x<device_modifier>.<filename_extension>
```

> The `<ImageName>` and `<filename_extension>` portions of each name specify the usual name and extension for the file. The `<device_modifier>` portion is optional and contains either the string `~ipad` or `~iphone`.
>
> You include one of these modifiers when you want to specify different versions of an image for iPad and iPhone. The inclusion of the `@2x` modifier for the high-resolution image is new and lets the system know that the image is the high-resolution variant of the standard image.

Comment: @Joseph, thanks for your reply. I have both these images but when I view in iPad, it does not select @2x image automatically...what could be wrong?

Comment: It is for the iPhone 4 that you need these images. The iPad does NOT have a retina display.

Comment: Ok...so if I want to use 2x images for iPad...what are my alternatives?

Comment: Please see my extended answer.

Comment: Note that the `<device_modifier>` designator only works for Universal apps: if you're creating a Universal app then it's exactly what you need. My answer is about iPhone-only apps that run at 2x on the iPad.

Comment: Standard: <ImageName><device_modifier>.<filename_extension>
High resolution: <ImageName>@2x<device_modifier>.<filename_extension>

Comment: Updated my answer. It's all in the manual you will find under the link I posted.

Answer (score 2):

The iPad has insufficient RAM to support iPhone pseudo-emulation with the `@2x` graphics, so the OS won't choose them automatically (as @Joseph Tura explained).

There are some techniques you can use to get the iPad to user higher-resolutions graphics while supporting both iPhone 4 Retina Display resolution and pre-iPhone-4 resolution, but it requires you do write all of the image substitution code yourself.

Matt Rix, creator of the excellent Trainyard games, explains how he did it inside Cocos 2D in a series of two posts: **[Retinafy Your Game](http://struct.ca/2010/retinafy-your-game/)** and **[High-res graphics in Cocos2D](http://struct.ca/2010/high-res-graphics-in-cocos2d/)**. If you play the iPhone-only (not Universal) **Trainyard** and **Trainyard Express** on your iPad, the graphics look great and don't have the pixel-doubled jaggy look because his code swaps in specific graphics if the iPhone game is being played on the iPad.

Even if you're not using Cocos 2D for game development, the same basic structure applies. I recommend taking a look.

Comment: The above links are broken. Google had no luck finding article's new location.